# How to determine the surface reaction rate and equilibrium constant for a reaction between a solid site species and gas species

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, surface-chemistry

Consider the following reaction mechanism [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbqE.jpg):

S1: $\ce{C-H (s) + H (g) <=> C^\star (s) + H2 (g)}$

S2: $\ce{C^\star (s) + H (g) => C-H (s)}$

S3: $\ce{C^\star (s) + C2H2 (g) => C-H (s) + H(g) + 2C(g)}$ Note that 2 C(g) in reality is not a gas but let's assumed it is for now.

S4: $\ce{C^\star (s) + C2H6 (g) <=> C-H (s) + C2H5(g)}$

The pre-exponential factor A in [cm<sup>3</sup>/(mol.s)][cm<sup>3</sup>/(mol.s)], n and activation energy E in cal/mol are respectively for each reaction:

S1: A = 4.2E+13,    n=0,     E=13,000

S2: A = 2.0E+13,    n=0,     E=0

S3: A = 8.0E+07, n=1.56,    E=3,800

S4: A = 2.1E+11,    n=0,     E=4,400

$\ce{C-H (s)}$ are $\ce{C^\star (s)}$ are the surface concentration on a soot (nucleated carbon) particle. $\ce{C-H(s)}$ is hydrogen occupied carbon and $\ce{C^\star}$ is unoccupied carbon.

The volumetric reactions rates can be determine using the following equation since the gas species are dependent on the availability of site species  [2] (I don't have any issues up to this stage):

r = k<sub>i</sub>C<sub>i</sub>$\frac{f_sX_s}{N_A}$,            i=1 to 4       ...... eq. 1

Where,

r = reaction rate, mol/m<sup>3</sup>.s

C = molar concentration of gaseous species in mol/m<sup>3</sup>

f<sub>s</sub> = ratio of number density of active surface sites on catalyst to that of soot.

X<sub>s</sub> = number density of surface sites on soot particles 1/m<sup>2</sup>.

N<sub>A</sub> = Avogadro's number 1/mol.

Now this is where I am having problems:

According to [2] it was provided that the number density of Cs-H can be approximated to be 2.3 x 10<sup>15</sup> cm<sup>-2</sup> based on experimental data. Estimated by considering one site in a
rectangular area with one side being half-width of the benzene ring.

If this number was divided by Avogadro's number we get the site concentration which is in agreement with the site concentration found in other sources (for example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbqE.jpg)) equivalent to 3.82 x 10<sup>-8</sup> kmol/m<sup>2</sup>.

The software that I am using deals with the site species using the following equations:

R*<sub>j,r</sub> = A<sub>p</sub>n<sub>r</sub>Y<sub>j</sub>R<sub>j,r</sub>       ...... eq. 2

R<sub>j,r</sub> = R<sub>kin,r</sub>(p<sub>n</sub> - $\frac{R_{j,r}}{D_{0,r}}$)<sup>N</sup>       ...... eq. 3

Where,

R*<sub>j,r</sub> = rate of particle species depletion kg/s.

A<sub>p</sub> = particle surface area m<sup>2</sup>.

Y<sub>j</sub> = mass fraction of surface species $j$ in the particle.

n<sub>r</sub> = effectiveness factor (dimensionless).

R<sub>j,r</sub> = rate of particle surface species reaction per unit area kg/m<sup>2</sup>.s.

P<sub>n</sub> = bulk partial pressure of the gas phase species (Pa).

D<sub>0,r</sub> = diffusion rate coefficient for reaction  $r$.

R<sub>kin,r</sub> = kinetic rate of reaction $r$ (units vary).

N = apparent order of reaction $r$.

The software does not know the number density or site concentrations of any of the site species and deals with them as mass species. I can only enter mass fractions with values 0 to 1 depending on the fraction of each species present in the particle. However, I know that the particle at t = 0 s is 100 nm in diameter. Therefore, based on the initial diameter and the site concentration of 3.82 x 10<sup>-8</sup> kmol/m<sup>2</sup> for Cs-H, I can work out the mass fractions for each species at t = 0 s assuming Cs* is zero initially (explanation why Cs* is zero is at the end of this post and should not affect anything here). For this reason I defined 3 mass fractions (these represent Y<sub>j</sub> in eq. 2):

1. Cs-H (the mass species that is occupied by hydrogen) = 0.012 at t = 0 s.
2. Cs* (the mass species that is unoccupied by hydrogen) = 0 at t= 0 s.
3. C<sub>c</sub> (the mass species representing the particle core and does not participate in the reaction) = 0.988 at t = 0 s.

***So now for the main questions,***

***Q1 I am not sure how to use A (pre-exponential factor) with the units mentioned in paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbqE.jpg) to get R<sub>j,r</sub> with units of kg/m<sup>2</sup>.s for each of the reactions S1 to S4.***

Update for Q1: I managed to find some sources mentioning that surface reactions like the above are considered unimolecular which is quite confusing if you have a pre-exponential factor with units of cm<sup>3</sup> /mol.s instead of 1/s.
Additionally, I managed to find a paper with the same mechanism for Appel [4] which mentions the following: "The rate coefficient of H combination with surface radical, reaction S1, was lowered from 1 x 10<sup>14</sup> cm<sup>3</sup>/mol.s to
2 x 10<sup>13</sup> cm<sup>3</sup>/mol.s". Does this indicate that the volume here is the volume of the reactor and not the particle itself?

***Q2 Also, are there any issues in using the standard equilibrium constant equation when dealing with reverse of reactions S1 and S4?***

Surface reaction mechanism S1 to S4 shown in the attachment (S5 to S8 are only third body collision reactions and are not part of the surface reaction mechanism).

Here is why Cs* is assumed zero at t=0s:

Simple answer to is very difficult to measure the number density or site concentration experimentally and it is usually calculated via a steady state assumption using the following [2]:

X<sub>C<sub>s</sub></sub> = $\frac{k_{1}[H] + k_{-4}[C2H5]}{k_{-1}[H2] + k_{2}[H] + k_{3}[C2H2] + k_{4}[C2H6]}$ X<sub>C<sub>s</sub>-H</sub>

I will not be using this equation as there no way to incorporate it in the software. I need to allow the reaction rates for each reaction to dictate the mass fractions.

References

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbqE.jpg) C. Kou, X. Yuan, Y. Luo, and X. Yuan, “Performance investigation of the solar thermal decomposition of methane reactor considering discrete and deposited carbon particles,” vol. 324, pp. 124401–124401, Sep. 2022, doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fuel.2022.124401.

[2] M. Younessi-Sinaki and F. Hamdullahpur, “Numerical investigation on the number of active surface sites of carbon catalysts in the decomposition of methane,” vol. 60, no. 6, pp. 2228–2234, Feb. 2014, doi: https://doi.org/10.1002/aic.14395.

[3] ANSYS Fluent Theory Guide, https://www.afs.enea.it/project/neptunius/docs/fluent/html/th/node136.htm

[4] J. Appel, H. Bockhorn, and M. Frenklach, “Kinetic modeling of soot formation with detailed chemistry and physics: laminar premixed flames of C2 hydrocarbons,” Combustion and Flame, vol. 121, no. 1–2, pp. 122–136, Apr. 2000, doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/s0010-2180(99)00135-2.

[image: Surface Reaction Mechanism]

Comment: Hello Rayana. If you have the full mechanism, I may be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Metal Storm, thanks for the reply. I have edited the post to include that info. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If doesn't give me much confidence about the paper you're using, when they in use arrows for mesomerism instead of for an equilibrium. Could you also please cite the full paper. Thank you!

Comment: From which article the given table $2$ is extracted ? What is the meaning of the index prime (') attached to $\ce{H}$ or to $\ce{C}$ in the given equations ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Martin-マーチン. I have added the reference to the post.

Comment: Hi @Maurice, thanks for the reply. I have added the reference in the post. Subscript s means (Solid) and refers to the carbon on the edge of particle. The asterisk means unoccupied carbon on the edge. The index prime (') does not have any special meaning and could have been avoided.

Comment: @MetalStorm I have edited with additional details. Looking forward to discuss.

Comment: @Rayana Thanks Rayana, I will try to answer it this weekend. Quick question, are you solving the state variables as a function of space and time? E.g., every gas has a partial pressure in the form of $P_j = P_j(x,t)$? Or you assume that the partial pressure has a unique value in the whole reactor, i.e., $P_j = P_j(t)$, like CSTR's.

Comment: @MetalStorm thanks Metal Storm. If there is any variation in the partial pressure that will be calculated in the background with respect to time.  I would be able to see it through the user interface. However, I'm not sure how easy or hard it is to extract these values with respect to each species to use it in an coded equation.

Comment: Hello Rayana. Some questions, I was reading the papers. (1) Why would you want to include the reverse reactions for $1-3$, since both papers list them as irreversible. At the start of your post, you list them as reversible. (2)  The Eq. (3) in your post seems to have a typo, $R_{j,r}$ appears at both sides. (3) The difussion coeffient refers to a *species*, not a *reaction*. Why is it dividing there? Where did you get that expression from? (4) Can you modify the code? Why can't you include that steady-state approximation equation?

Comment: (1) According to ref. [1] and [2], S1 and S4 are reversible reactions.
(2) Yes, you are right it might be a typo. If you go to ref. [3] and scroll down a little, you'll find that equations 7.3-7 to 7.3-9 are the relevant ones. But it really doesn't matter because these equations can be overwritten by any equation that I code as long as the units is kgmol/m2.s.

Comment: I was thinking of overwriting equations 2 and 3 with a simple decomposition equation mentioned here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_on_surfaces) where k2 is rate constant for the surface reaction (1/s) and k1 the rate constant for surface adsorption (m3/mol.s). In my case I think I am given k1 but not k2. Not sure how to get k2.

Comment: (3) Not sure about the diffusion and it probably doesn't matter because these equations will be overwritten by a rate equation which I can code in. I just provided them thinking they might help or provide any clues.

Comment: (4) I can't use that particular steady state approximation given in the paper because it calculates the site concentration of Cs* at steady state rather than a rate. I need to input a rate with units kgmol/m2.s and that rate can calculate the site concentration at steady state.

Comment: @Rayana I am still thinking about it, I am going to consult some colleagues in university. Are you in a hurry with your code? Sorry of not being able to answer this weekend, because I have some doubts. I am sure I will make it this week. Are you taking into account the effectiveness factor? Have you seen the process of reaction-diffusion in a catalyst pellet in spherical geometry? You come from chemistry or engineering?

Comment: That's okay thanks for your help. No I don't need to consider effectiveness factor. I can overwrite the rate equation with anything else no matter how simple as long as the rate is in kgmol/m2.s. I have not seen the reaction I'm trying to simulate it as close as possible by using kinetic parameters and comparing results with literature. I come from an engineering background and trying to simulate the autocatalytic effect of methane decomposition. Before we reach the mechanism presented in this post I already modelled a 37 step homogeneous mechanism which leads to it show in table 1 of ref [1].